# Print list items in a rectangular frame

Tags: python, formatting, ascii-art

The aim is to have that:

```
list ["Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame"]
```

And make it printed like this:

> ```
> *********
> * Hello *
> * World *
> * in    *
> * a     *
> * frame *
> *********
> ```

I did this and it works fine:

```py
a = 0
for nb in listA:
    if a == 0:
        print("*"*10).center(20)
    a += 1
    if len(nb) == 2:
        print("*   " + nb + "   *").center(20)
    elif len(nb) == 1:
        print("*   " + nb + "    *").center(20)
    else:
        print("* " + nb + "  *").center(20)
    if a == len(listA):
        listA[-1]
        print("*"*10).center(20)
```

Still, I feel it is very cumbersome. Do you have any ideas how I can improve it, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can let [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) do most of the work for you:

```
def print_in_a_frame(*words):
    size = max(len(word) for word in words)
    print('*' * (size + 4))
    for word in words:
        print('* {:<{}} *'.format(word, size))
    print('*' * (size + 4))

>>> print_in_a_frame("Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame")
*********
* Hello *
* World *
* in    *
* a     *
* frame *
*********
```

Most of the *magic* happens in this line:

```
print('* {:<{}} *'.format(word, size))
```

It may be easier to understand what's going on if we rewrite it as:

```
print('* {a:<{b}} *'.format(a=word, b=size))
```

This tells format to print the keyword argument `a`, left-aligned, on a field of total width the keyword argument `b`.  Note that if `b` was fixed, say to 10, you would write that as:

```
print('* {a:<10}} *'.format(a=word))
```

or:

```
print('* {:<10}} *'.format(word))
```

Comment: Hi @jaime, thanks for your answer.Can you explain a bit more this part, please `{:<{}}`

Comment: It probably looks like your face trying to figure it out... `;-)` Have added a more detailed explanation, see if it makes sense...

Comment: Close enough @jamie my face would look like this -_-' Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 4):

@Jaime's answer was quite good. I can only suggest a couple very minor changes, mostly just to show some alternative methods.

### Get length of longest item in a list

The `max()` function takes an optional 2nd argument (if the first argument is an iterable) to specify a one-argument ordering function. So instead of computing `size` as:

```
size = max(len(word) for word in words)
```

you could compute it as:

```
size = len(max(words, key=len))
```

I'd make the argument that the first method (Jaime's) is more readable: it's a very simple and clear use of a list comprehension that *almost* reads like straight English — which is about as *literate programming* as you can hope for!

However, if for some reason (not in the OP's problem) you needed the actual longest string rather than its length, `longstr = max(words, key=len)` is the canonical Pythonic way to get it. If I had been used to using that, my first thought would probably be to just wrap that with a `len()`, *et voila*.

### Let `print_in_a_frame()` accept custom bounding character

First, I suggest letting `print_in_a_frame()` take a list of strings, rather than an arbitrary number of arguments (each being one of the strings to print). The reason I suggest it is to enable the following...

Second, if for some reason you decide to change the bounding character from `*` to something else, why not do the following:

```
def print_in_a_frame(words, borderchar = '*'):
    size = max(len(word) for word in words)
    print(borderchar * (size + 4))
    for word in words:
        print('{bc} {:<{}} {bc}'.format(word, size, bc = borderchar))
    print(borderchar * (size + 4))
```

(Note the `words` argument is not preceded with the argument-packing operator `*`; thus `words` can be a list). Now you can do the following:

```
>>> print_in_a_frame("Box this message".split())
***********
* Box     *
* this    *
* message *
***********

>>> print_in_a_frame("Box this message".split(), '+')
+++++++++++
+ Box     +
+ this    +
+ message +
+++++++++++
```

Now, as it is, there is no checking if the 2nd argument in my suggestion for `print_in_a_frame()` is a single character:

```
>>> print_in_a_frame("Box this message".split(), '*:')
*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:
*: Box     *:
*: this    *:
*: message *:
*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:
```

so perhaps, if you only ever wanted to box text with `*` characters, this suggestion can lead to scope creep, and before you know it you're [shaving a yak](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving).